# Trying to query a database by current user, but Django stops at template if statement

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance if I am somehow not abiding by the question asking etiquette.

Currently trying to query the database represented by this model,

## Models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Things(models.Model):
     posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
     thing1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     thing2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     thing3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

by the current user in this view,

## Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app.models import Things

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def things(request):
    user = request.user
    results = Things.objects.filter(posted_by__exact=user)
    return render(request, 'my_things.html', {'results' : results})
```

corresponding to this url,

## Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from app import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^profile/things/$',views.things),
)
```

and this template:

## my_things.html

```
    {% if results %} 
        {% for thing in results %}
      <h1>{{thing.thing1}} and {{thing.thing2}} and {{thing.thing2}}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <h1>You have no things!</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

The error Django gives me when I try to load the page is an OperationalError saying there is "no such table: app_Things".

Comment: One a side note: you dont need the `__exact` criteria. Just do `posted_by=request.user`. Also, did you run the migrations properly ? are the database tables created in the database?

Comment: I assume you synced/migrated?

Comment: yeah whenever I try to run migrations it says there is nothing to migrate.  The tables are created as I see everything there when I run ./manage.py sqlall app

Comment: Double-check with `inspectdb` to make sure everything is in the right spot. `sqlall app` will give you the SQL command that it would use to migrate, but if something is malformed within the db itself it won't necessarily reveal that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see it when I checked, but I saw all the other tables that were created.  How could I delete all tables and resync them?

Comment: @kpacn has it right; make sure the app is in your settings then sync things up. If you don't care about data loss in the DB, I'd just dump the whole thing and sync from scratch.

Comment: @souldeux - I used manage.py flush and then used syncdb. I originally did have app in my settings.py.  it appears to be all there after I inspectdb, but the foreginkey field is showing up as a charfield.  I also have another table in models.py that uses settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as a foreignkey, could that be the problem?

Comment: Oh yeah, if it's a custom AUTH_USER_MODEL then that's probably your issue. Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model especially noting in the first warning the issues you may encounter regarding your database schema. If you're not using a custom user model but are instead just wanting to foreignkey to the built-in User object, you need to `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and tie your relations to the User model rather than the thing referenced in `settings`.

Comment: @souldeux finally fixed it. thank you (and everyone else) for all of your help

Comment: No worries; I'm going to post it as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, the diagnosis: traditional bugginess with a custom AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Check this: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) especially noting in the first warning the issues you may encounter regarding your database schema. If you're not using a custom user model but are instead just wanting to foreignkey to the built-in User object, you need to from django.contrib.auth.models import User and tie your relations to the User model rather than the thing referenced in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add your app name in INSTALLED_APPS in settings file and syncdb after that. Also this __exact query is not needed.